# how to integrate validity of nested form in the main form

Tags: angular6

I have a component `A` which looks like this

[image]

In summary, a user can create different sections/answers and can save them. A rectangular button is created for each saved answer. Internally, all this is saved in Forms and is validated. I am using `ace-editor` which already provides capability to use the editor as form control.

snippet from A.ts

```
  createForm() {
    this.codeEditorForm = this.fb.group({
      answer: [null, [this.validateThereIsAtleastOneSavedAnswer(this.answers),this.validateThereIsNoUnsavedAnswer(this.answers)]],
    });
  }
```

snippet from A.html

```
<ace-editor id="editor" class="form-control" formControlName="answer" [ngClass]="validateField('answer')" [(text)]="text"></ace-editor>
```

I want to use this component as a form control in other components. For eg. I have another component `B` which also has a `form`

B.ts
    this.bForm = this.fb.group({
          field1: [null],
          field2: [null],
          field3: [null, Validators.required],
          field4: [null], 
          field5: [null], //the value of A maps to this field of the form in B
          field6: [null]
        },);
      }

B.html

```
<A #a [readonlyFormStatus]="readonlyFormStatus" (answerSectionsEmitter)="handleAEvent($event)" class="form-control" formControlName="field5" [ngClass]="validateField('field5')" ></A>
```

I want that when `bform` is submitted only when validation of both `bForm` and `aForm` have passed.

What would be the right way to do this following Angular design philosophy?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way seems to be that `A` implements `ControlValueAccessor` interface.

```
export class A implements OnInit, AfterViewInit,  ControlValueAccessor {
...

...
}
```

"There’s the `DefaultValueAccessor` that takes care of text `inputs` and `textareas`, the `SelectControlValueAccessor` that handles `select` inputs, or the `CheckboxControlValueAccessor`, which, surprise, deals with `checkboxes`, and many more. So for these UI elements, we don't need to create value accessors but for custom components, we need to create a custom accessor" - https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Explanation - I am asking `formB` to take value of `A` and map it to `field5` of `formB`. But `Angular` doesn't know what is the value of `A`. For `input` fields, `Angular` already knows that the value of the text box is the value which gets  mapped to a form control. But for custom components, we have to explicitly tell `Angular` what is the value the custom components generates which gets mapped to a `form`'s field. This is done by implementing `ControlValueAccess` interface.

The interface has 3 important methods.
1) `writeValue` which is way to tell how the UI changes if the model changes. Say UI of the custom component was a slider with left-end meaning 0% and right-end meaning 100%. If the model changes to say a value say 10/100 then the UI needs to slide to 10%. Update this method to change the UI. In my case, I didn't need to do anything in it because the data input direction in my case is UI to model and not model to UI (my model doesn't create text which needs to be filled in the text region.

```
writeValue(value:any){
    console.log('write value called with value ',value);
  }
```

2) `registerOnChange`  - this is reverse of `writeValue`. Whenever the UI changes, the model needs to be changed as well. In my case, whenever user writes in textbox then I want to update my model. "Angular provides you with a function and asks you to call it whenever there is a change in your component with the new value so that it can update the control." - https://netbasal.com/angular-custom-form-controls-made-easy-4f963341c8e2

In my case, I want to propogate changes then `A`'s save button is clicked (`onSaveAnswer` is called then).  I want to propogate value of all saved answers at this time

```
answers:Array<AnswerInformation>;
propagateChange = (_: any) => {};

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    console.log('registerOnchange called');
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  inSaveAnswer(){
...
    this.propagateChange(this.answers);
  }
```

The value that gets propogated gets mapped to the form field to which `A` is mapped to.

```
<A #a [readonlyFormStatus]="readonlyFormStatus" (answerSectionsEmitter)="handleAEvent($event)" class="form-control" formControlName="field5" [ngClass]="validateField('field5')" ></A>
```

`field5` will contain the values proporated (this.answers). its structure will be `Array<AnswerInformation>;` i.e. `field5:Array<AnswerInformation>;`

I could put addition verification that `field5` is not an empty array like so

```
field5: [null, this.validateField5IsProvided]

  validateField5IsProvided(control:AbstractControl) {

      const f5:Array<AnswerInformation> = control.value;
      if(f5){
        if(f5.length !== 0){
          // console.log('answer field is valid');
          return null;
        } else {
          return {
            validateAnswerIsSaved: { // check the class ShowErrorsComponent to see how validatePassword is used.
              valid: false,
              message: 'The field can\'t be empty. Please make sure to save the field'
            }
          };
        }
      } else {
        return {
          validateAnswerIsSaved: { 
            valid: false,
            message: 'The fieldcan\'t be empty. Please make sure to save the field'
          }
        };
      }
    }
```

There are couple of more functions that need to be implemented as well

```
registerOnTouched() {
    console.log('registerOnTouched called');
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    console.log('set disabled called with value ',isDisabled);
    this.editor.setReadOnly(isDisabled);
  }
```